# How to install libimobiledevice?

Tags: 11.10

Just as the title states how do I install that library to manage my iPhone?

Comment: On my 12.04 the target sorce list file is here:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-precise.list
I have changed precise by maverick, but I still got Package not found error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First try this:

1. Type in terminal `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa`
2. Then run `sudo apt-get update`.
3. Then run `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice`.

If it says **Package not found**:

1. Type in terminal `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery.list`
2. It will open **Gedit**, a text editor. Replace these two lines...

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
   ```

   ...with these two lines:

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. Then again in terminal, run `sudo apt-get update`.
5. Then run `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice`.

Comment: On 12.04 I got this response, even editing back to maverick as you suggested. W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: That's why you need to replace `oneiric` or `precise` by `maverick`.