# How do I get my ipod to conect using libmobiledevice

Tags: ipod

So I have tried all the basic things to install including

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
```

All it does is report 'command not found'.

Entering the command

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery.list
```

pulls up a blank file.

I do have `wine` installed but I am looking for an alternative if it's not possible to use it under `wine`. Using `itunes` under `wine` would be great too, however.

It seems as if nothing will recognize my ipod, but when I type:

```
lsusb | grep Apple
```

I get

```
Bus 005 Device 015: ID 05ac:1293 Apple Computer, Inc.
```

Are there any solutions for these problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which release you are using, so my answer might not be correct in every detail. In addition, there are already some helpful hints in answers to this question: [How to install libimobiledevice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78535/how-to-install-libimobiledevice)

To sum up all steps needed, especially under releases newer than maverick:

**Do the following under your own risk**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pmcenery/ppa
```

You shouild then get/got a waring like this:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:

More info: https://launchpad.net/~pmcenery/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

Press enter and then continue with

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-precise.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-maverick.list
```

Now open the file and change all entries from "oneiric" to "maverick":

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-maverick.list
```

In the end, this should be in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-maverick.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
```

You should now be able to install libimobiledevice1:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice1
```