# Errors with installing libimobiledevice

Tags: 14.04, apt, music, mp3, iphone

I tried to install `libimobiledevice` only to see that I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libimobiledevice
```

I found [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78535/how-to-install-libimobiledevice) which I try to follow, but there was no file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery.list` I can edit, only a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-trusty.list` in which I replaced the line

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

with

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu maverick main
```

But after that (and `apt-get update`) the same error remains. I can even produce another error as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libimobiledevice1 : Depends: libtasn1-3 (>= 1.6-0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I  install `libimobiledevice` on Ubuntu 14.045 LTS in order to transfer music files (mp3) to an `iphone 6`, so I can listen to the music on this very `iphone 6`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are landing here with `Ubuntu 20.04 Focal` then you need to run `sudo apt install libimobiledevice6 usbmuxd libimobiledevice-utils`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to mount iPhone with the ifuse tool. So after you install libimobiledevice6 as you did, you mount the iPhone with ifuse.

But first you need to install some packages including what you installed. To help others who see this question I'll explain how I do it from scratch:

```
sudo apt-get install ideviceinstaller python-imobiledevice libimobiledevice-utils libimobiledevice6 libplist3 python-plist ifuse
```

Then plug in the iPhone to a USB port and pair the iPhone:

```
idevicepair pair
```

Note: if you get an error "ERROR: Could not validate with device xxxxxxxxxx because a passcode is set. Please enter the passcode on the device and retry." 
unlock the iPhone and choose "Trust" in the security popup and repeat the command above.

Next you mount the iPhone with ifuse:

```
ifuse /media/iPhone/
```

You can run ifuse command above as root (sudo) or as a regular user, depending if you want to allow users to mount and unmount your iPhone.

To unmount the iPhone, which you should do to avoid problems mounting in future use the following commands one after the other:

```
fusermount -u /media/iPhone/
idevicepair unpair
```

More info here:
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html

Comment: Doesn't work. Says "Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device."

Answer (score 0):

The PPA you added is outdated - the need to change to "maverick" should have been a clue - so now it needs to be removed before adding the correct one:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pmcenery/ppa
```

(or just remove it and run `sudo apt-get update` since you actually didn't install anything from it)

Install using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:martin-salbaba/ppa+libimobiledevice
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice
```

All the dependencies should be pulled from this repository.

Please note that it may not work for your intended purpose. You are always at the mercy of a Linux-unfriendly manufacturer. News & updates at http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

Comment: With the last command I get the same error as before (`E: Unable to locate package libimobiledevice`), but the following worked: `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice6`. As I suppose this is a library ('lib-imobile-device'), how is it supposed to work?